# How to get a value by id or class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following html code like this:

```
<div class="question">
<input class="cross-reference-question-value-id" id="enr_rds_question_ids" name="enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref[enr_rds_question_id]" type="hidden" value="30"> 
</div>
```

In this html, the value=15 is the value by the user selected in the front-end. Now I want to store the id into the following script.

```
var survey_question_type = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('enr_rds_question_id').value)[30];
```

Here, the user selected the value `30`. I want to define a `variable` for the `question_id` field and store that `variable` to the script instead of `[30]`.

Comment: Please explain it again, it's not clear what you want and also not clear what the problem is, also HTML code would be nice !

Comment: is in the name and in the id `enr_rds_question_id` replaced programatically with a value? I'm not sure you can use integer values as id's - link to authors fiddle jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/veq2V

Comment: Am not using the id to get the value. i am just trying and i can change to anything to get the value. Because i am new to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like in this fiddle what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/veq2V/1/

Comment: In the console JSON.parse(document.getElementById('enr_rds_question_id').value)[30]; is working. So, I want to give the variable name or anything instead of 30. Then only it will change as per the user selection.

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle if none of this helps so that I can better understand what's happening, I have no information about your html structure or any of the fields, so it's very hard to give you any useful information this way.

Comment: Here i explain. My javascript is very big. So just i edited the html and mention what i need to do in the css area. http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/veq2V/

Comment: document.getElementById('enr_rds_question_id').value is already 15, you don't need to wrap it into the json.parse and use it as an array.

Comment: I edited my answer, I'm still not sure I understand the actual question or the structure of your html in enough detail.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the same. Now, what i want to do is i want to define a variable for that value to call that variable to some other place in the same js file.

Comment: you mean like i defined it in html? `<input type="hidden" id="question_id" value="17">` , you can just use a var or update the hidden field in my example

Comment: i used the var question_id = document.getElementById('enr_rds_question_id').value But it says, question_id is not defined

Comment: try removing the var, leave just `question_id = document.getElementById('enr_rds_question_id').value;`

Comment: yeah now i got it. Thank you xception. You are so kind.

Answer (score 1):

If I understnad the quesion correctly do as below

```
var survey_question_type = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('enr_rds_question_id').value)[$('enr_rds_question_ids').val()]
```

for that to work `document.getElementById('enr_rds_question_id').value` has to represent an array. I.e. be a string of the format `"[obj0,obj1,...,objn]"`

Comment: @Vinay I was a bit unclear it has to represent an array. I.e. be a string of the format `"[elm,elm1,elm2,...elmn]"`

Comment: JSON.parse(document.getElementById('enr_rds_question_id').value)[30] This script is working fine in the console. So, the id should be the array i guess

Comment: Thank you Rune. Thanks for your help. Mistake is mine. I am not defined the question properly. Now i got it. Thanks